# Why does the browser not want to place the text between the <tr> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I want to put the table rows with javascript in the HTML.
Why is *trRight* not between the *tr* tags?

I have also tested in other browsers and it's the same issue.

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
    <body>
      <table>
        <tbody>
                <!--Javascript puts code here-->
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </body>
    <script>
     document.querySelector("tbody").innerHTML += "<tr>trRight</tr>";
     document.querySelector("tbody").innerHTML += "<trWrong>trWrong</trWrong>";
    </script>
  </html>
```

Result:

[image: result of the code]

Comment: A tr does not have text nodes as a child.

Comment: Because you can never add anything to a TR other than other table elements like TD or TH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<tr>` is a table row it [doesn't allow contents](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html) to be placed other than `<td>` or `<th>`, you have to place your content only inside `<td>` like this:

```
document.querySelector("tbody").innerHTML += "<tr><td>trRight</td></tr>";
```

While `<trWrong>` is not a valid tag, still browser considers it as a [custom tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/) and hence encloses your text.

<sub>[Thanks [@skyline3000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828864/skyline3000) for valid link for `<tr>` tag]</sub>

Comment: `<tr>` tags are not permitted to contain anything other than `<td>` or `<th>` elements, see the spec:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html

You can wrap your text in either of those elements.